# I can't login to vps ubuntu after change ssh port

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, ssh, sshd

After changing the port from 22 to 2200 from `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
then I run :
`sudo service ssh restart`

I disabled the UFW and by check `sudo service ssh status`
it's working and listing to port 2200 but when I try to connect by this line :

```
sudo ssh -vvv -i LightsailDefaultPrivateKey-us-east-1.pem ubuntu@54.144.30.218 -p 2200
```

it gives me `time out`, if I change the port again to 22, it'll work, but I want to use another port inside of 22, 2222 gives me the same issue

**my ubuntu VPS from amazon lightsail**

Comment: This sounds like a firewall issue. I bet they block all ports except some select ones

Comment: @mbeyss but I stopped the UFW from work and still not working in addition to that if it's from the firewall, should give me permission denied not time out?

Comment: Sorry I did not express that clearly enough. I mean amazon is blocking the port.

Comment: yes,  you are right I found that now thank you very much

Comment: Please formulate an answer to your own question, linking some resources and accept this

Answer (score 2):

the Machine and firewall settings were fine but Amazone was blocking all ports except 80 & 22 so after edit it and add my ports to Amazone lightsail firewall machine , everything works file